# Grouping and Aggregating in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am quite new to spring data elasticsearch.
 **I wanted to know is there any way that i can group an index records based on one field's value and perform aggregations at each group level.**
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks & Regards
 Sumanth K P

Comment: Can you give an example of what your documents consist of? What have you tried till now?